# Do we need to repeat the verb after and?

Tags: ellipsis, idiomatic-language

> Pupils at the primary education level are less violent and **are**
>   hard workers.

**Do we need "*are*" and what is the natural thing to do?**

Comment: “pupils in primary school” is more natural than “pupils at the primary education level”.

Answer (score 3):

As the sentence stands, you need the second **are** in there for 2 reasons.

1. The mix of adjective (violent) and noun (worker) without the second **are** sounds awkward (to me at least)
2. Without the second **are** it could be construed that they are *less hard workers*

Having two **are**'s in close proximity might seem a little clumsy though. (could just be me).

To fix this I would suggest a more natural sounding way to say this would be to switch them around:

> Pupils at the primary education level are harder working and less violent.

Answer (score 0):

Either is acceptable, but if you repeat the verb, it will be less confusing.

With the repeated verb, it is clear that you mean to say that the pupils [are less violent (in general)] and [are hard workers].

Without the repeated verb, it could also be (mis)understood that you mean to say that the pupils are [less violent workers] and [hard workers], or even that the pupils are [less violent workers] and [less hard (diligent) workers].

Comment: Do you mean "less hard workers" in the second example of the second paragraph?

Comment: You know, that's a third way it could be understood. I'll edit.